# Ionic2 loader.present query

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic2. I am using LoadingController like,

```
this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait, creating new test...",
});
this.loader.present();
```

after that in some function I use `this.loader.dismiss();`

I want to know that after loader.dismiss, is there any way to check if loader is present or not, e.g. `loader.present == true`

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand..once it is dismissed, a loader object cannot be used again..you will have to create a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `onDidDismiss()` function.

you can have a boolean value set:

```
this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Please wait, creating new test...",
});
let isShowingLoading:boolean=true;

this.loader.onDidDismiss(()=>isShowingLoading=false);
this.loader.present()
```

Check [API here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/)

Comment: Hi Suraj , can you help me to answer this question related to infinite scroll ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281506/related-to-ion-infinite-scroll-in-ionic2