# Related to ion-infinite-scroll in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am facing an issue with `ion-infinite-scroll` in my Ionic2 application. Please find the below code.

### Code

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite()" distance="5%">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
            </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

### `doInfinite()` method

```
doInfinite(){
    if(this.myReportList.length < this.reportCount){
        console.log("Inside doInfinite if");
        this.loadMore=true;
        this.startFrom = this.endTo+1; // for the time time the value of startFrom is 0 and endTo is 10.
        this.endTo = this.endTo+10;
        this.viewMyReports();
    }else{
        console.log("Inside doInfinite else");
        this.loadMore=false;
        this.genericService.showToast("Reached Bottom")
    }
}
```

In my case the `doInfinite()` method is invoked only for the first 2 times . Even though `if(this.myReportList.length < this.reportCount){` 
is true . Could anyone please tell me why the method is not invoking ?

### Scenario

Say I am having a total count of 50 and for the first time i am listing first 10 records , then when I reach the end of reports it again call the `doInfinite()` method with `startFrom` and `endTo` 11 and 20 respectively . But for the third time onwards the `ion-infinite-scroll` is not invoking the method . 
Please help me with this .

### Edit

`this.viewMyReports();` is the API call from where I am getting the reports

### HTML  Page

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let XX of responseList">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col col-7>
                        <p {{XX.***}}</p>
                        <p {{XX.***}}</p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-5>
                        <p> Submitted</p>
                        <p >{{XX.***}}</p>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-card>
```

Thanks and Regards

Anand Raj

Comment: @sebaferreras , Can you help me with this ?

Comment: what does `this.viewMyReports()` do? and   does `console.log("Inside doInfinite else");` get printed?

Comment: this.viewMyReports() is my API call . console.log("Inside doInfinite else"); will print only for the first 1 ,2 times . After that " this.viewMyReports() " is not firing

Comment: if it is printing first two times.. it never goes to if.. what is `this.reportCount` value?

Comment: total count is 520 . It is showing " Loading more data... " after 1 ,2 scroll but api is not invoking

Comment: @AnandRaj, did my solution work?

Comment: @Swapnil Patwa, I am checking . Will update you soon .

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `infiniteScroll.complete();`

> Call complete() within the infinite output event handler when your
>   async operation has completed. For example, the loading state is while
>   the app is performing an asynchronous operation, such as receiving
>   more data from an AJAX request to add more items to a data list. Once
>   the data has been received and UI updated, you then call this method
>   to signify that the loading has completed. This method will change the
>   infinite scroll’s state from loading to enabled.

Try this-

**HTML:**

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" distance="5%">
                <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
                </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

**TS:**

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll: any){
    if(this.myReportList.length < this.reportCount){
        console.log("Inside doInfinite if");
        this.loadMore=true;
        this.startFrom = this.endTo+1; // for the time time the value of startFrom is 0 and endTo is 10.
        this.endTo = this.endTo+10;
        this.viewMyReports();
    }else{
        console.log("Inside doInfinite else");
        this.loadMore=false;
        this.genericService.showToast("Reached Bottom")
    }
infiniteScroll.complete();
}
```

Comment: Hi , I am getting one error . " ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found " .

Comment: Any loader is there?

Comment: Yes . The loader is dismissed once i got the response

Comment: Comment out that loader and try.

Comment: comment " this.loader.dismiss(); " ?

Comment: Not even create. Try removing entire loader

Comment: Your solution is working .Marking it as useful . Thanks

Comment: Now put loader back, and if you keep getting that error create a new issue with releted code

Comment: Hi , I am facing one issue with your solution . infiniteScroll is invoked multiple times for a single scroll

Comment: try removing `distance="5%"`

Comment: even after i removed the distance ="5%"  , facing the same issue

Comment: Add HTML where you are doing `*ngFor`.

Comment: try removing  `ion-item`

Comment: please tell me why ?

Comment: or   <ion-item *ngFor="let XX of responseList"> <ion-card> </ion-card></ion-item>

Comment: weird. something seems wrong with structure, although i am not sure what is exactly wrong. but you can try removing `ion-item` and `ion-list`.

Comment: Or try .complete on success of api call. Although you need .complete anyways. `https://plnkr.co/edit/9dV3mc?p=preview`